# Use phpcassandra in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, cassandra

Hi I am new to cassandra database. I am trying to do a project in codeigniter with cassandra database. I have downloaded the phpcassandra files through below link
https://github.com/mauritsl/php-cassandra.

When I am trying to autoload my casssandra.php in codeigniter I got Non-existent class: Cassandra error. Why I got this error and how to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a wrapper for it if you wish to use it as a library.

I would suggest you take the [composer](https://getcomposer.org/) route.
You can check on [packagist](https://packagist.org/search/?q=cassandra) for a suitable library.

If you use this particular library [phpcassa](https://packagist.org/packages/thobbs/phpcassa) this is how you would go about getting it to work in Codeigniter.

## composer.json

```
{
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.0",
        "thobbs/phpcassa": "1.1.0"
    }

}
```

## index.php

```
require "../composer/autoload.php";
```

## system/core/codeigniter.php

```
// Where codeigniter starts to load the Main Controller
// $cassandraDB will be in the GLOBAL scope, so you may want to write a wrapper

$cassandraDB = new ConnectionPool('localhost');

// Then right after this
// if (class_exists('CI_DB') AND isset($CI->db))
// {
//      $CI->db->close();
// }

$cassandraDB->close();
```

## User Model

implement it how you wish in your models

```
public function __construct()
{
    //YOU MAY NEED TO PASS $cassandraDB AS A DEPENDANCY!!

    $this->users = new ColumnFamily($cassandraDB, 'Standard1');
}
```

Comment: I tried to use Thrift package in cassandra which is almost similar to thobbs package.But it seems to be more difficult to access datas in database.Can you write some queries using thobbs/phpcassa package to access datas in cassandra database?

Comment: Hi Philip can you explain how to use execute_cql_query() in thobbs/lib/cassandra/Cassandra.php

Comment: I'm not familiar with the library sorry! Check the API Document.